# Subsetting a string into an uneven list and logically propagating a data.frame from the list

Tags: r

I have spent a good deal of time trying to solve this problem and have been unsuccessful.

I have a data.frame with a column containing strings of variable lengths. The data.frame looks like this:

```
Taxa <- as.character(c("cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Actinobacteria(phylum)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Enterobacteriales(order)_Enterobacteriaceae(family)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Enterobacteriales(order)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Enterobacteriales(order)_Enterobacteriaceae(family)_Klebsiella(genus)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Enterobacteriales(order)_Enterobacteriaceae(family)_Klebsiella(genus)_Klebsiellapneumoniae(species)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Firmicutes(phylum)_Clostridia(class)_Clostridiales(order)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Firmicutes(phylum)_Clostridia(class)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Firmicutes(phylum)_Clostridia(class)_Clostridiales(order)_Clostridiaceae(family)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Firmicutes(phylum)_Clostridia(class)_Clostridiales(order)_Clostridiaceae(family)_Clostridium(genus)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Firmicutes(phylum)_Clostridia(class)_Clostridiales(order)_Clostridiaceae(family)_Clostridium(genus)_Clostridiumbotulinum(species)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Firmicutes(phylum)_Clostridia(class)_Clostridiales(order)_Clostridiaceae(family)_Clostridium(genus)_Clostridiumbotulinum(species)_ClostridiumbotulinumCDC66177(strain)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Actinobacteria(phylum)_Actinobacteria(class)_Actinobacteridae(subclass)_Actinomycetales(order)_Micrococcineae(suborder)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Actinobacteria(phylum)_Actinobacteria(class)_Actinobacteridae(subclass)_Actinomycetales(order)_Micrococcineae(suborder)_Microbacteriaceae(family)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Actinobacteria(phylum)_Actinobacteria(class)_Actinobacteridae(subclass)_Actinomycetales(order)_Micrococcineae(suborder)_Microbacteriaceae(family)_Microbacterium(genus)","cellularorganisms(norank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Actinobacteria(phylum)_Actinobacteria(class)_Actinobacteridae(subclass)_Actinomycetales(order)_Micrococcineae(suborder)_Microbacteriaceae(family)_Microbacterium(genus)_Microbacteriumlaevaniformans(species)_MicrobacteriumlaevaniformansOR221(strain)"))
Percent <- c("0.000400","0.006800","0.005034","0.001760","0.000000","0.000000","0.344400","0.000000","0.000000","0.000000","0.006500","0.002819","0.000487","0.000000","0.001090")
Test <- data.frame(Percent, Taxa)
Test$Taxa <- as.character(Test$Taxa)
```

I can subset these strings on the underscores into a list of unequal lengths:

```
NewDF <- strsplit(Test$Taxa, "_", fixed=TRUE)
```

But I can't figure out how to take this parsed output and format it into a usable structure.

Each parsed section has two components, a descriptor and a taxonomic level (i.e. Bacteria(superkingdom) is the descriptor Bacteria and the taxonomic level superkingdom.

What I want to do is to take this parsed output, and populate a data.frame that has the following column headers (norank, superkingdom, phylum, class, order, family, genus, species, strain). The output needs to skip taxonomic levels that are not included in the list above though (for example, there are rows with a taxonomic level of subclass between class and order, I need to drop subclass).

Additionally, if a line stops at a specific taxonomic level and there are still unfilled columns, they should be set to NA (i.e. the first row ends at phylum, so class, order, family and so on should be NA).

The final output should look like this:

```
                      norank           superkingdom                 phylum                      class                    order                     family                 genus                               species                                    strain
1  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Actinobacteria(phylum)                       <NA>                     <NA>                       <NA>                  <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
2  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Proteobacteria(phylum) Gammaproteobacteria(class) Enterobacteriales(order) Enterobacteriaceae(family)                  <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
3  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Proteobacteria(phylum) Gammaproteobacteria(class) Enterobacteriales(order)                       <NA>                  <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
4  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Proteobacteria(phylum) Gammaproteobacteria(class) Enterobacteriales(order) Enterobacteriaceae(family)     Klebsiella(genus)                                                                            <NA>
5  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Proteobacteria(phylum) Gammaproteobacteria(class) Enterobacteriales(order) Enterobacteriaceae(family)     Klebsiella(genus)         Klebsiellapneumoniae(species)                                      <NA>
6  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom)     Firmicutes(phylum)          Clostridia(class)     Clostridiales(order)                       <NA>                  <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
7  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom)     Firmicutes(phylum)          Clostridia(class)                     <NA>                       <NA>                  <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
8  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom)     Firmicutes(phylum)          Clostridia(class)     Clostridiales(order)     Clostridiaceae(family)                  <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
9  cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom)     Firmicutes(phylum)          Clostridia(class)     Clostridiales(order)     Clostridiaceae(family)    Clostridium(genus)                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
10 cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom)     Firmicutes(phylum)          Clostridia(class)     Clostridiales(order)     Clostridiaceae(family)    Clostridium(genus)         Clostridiumbotulinum(species)                                      <NA>
11 cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom)     Firmicutes(phylum)          Clostridia(class)     Clostridiales(order)     Clostridiaceae(family)    Clostridium(genus)         Clostridiumbotulinum(species)      ClostridiumbotulinumCDC66177(strain)
12 cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Actinobacteria(phylum)      Actinobacteria(class)   Actinomycetales(order)                       <NA>                  <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
13 cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Actinobacteria(phylum)      Actinobacteria(class)   Actinomycetales(order)  Microbacteriaceae(family)                  <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
14 cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Actinobacteria(phylum)      Actinobacteria(class)   Actinomycetales(order)  Microbacteriaceae(family) Microbacterium(genus)                                  <NA>                                      <NA>
15 cellularorganisms(norank) Bacteria(superkingdom) Actinobacteria(phylum)      Actinobacteria(class)   Actinomycetales(order)  Microbacteriaceae(family) Microbacterium(genus) Microbacteriumlaevaniformans(species) MicrobacteriumlaevaniformansOR221(strain)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing it by compiling a list of small data.frames into one df

```
library(dplyr)

NewDF <- 
  lapply(strsplit(Test$Taxa, "_", fixed=TRUE),
         function(x)
         {
           vars <- lapply(x, function(y)
           {
             m <- regexec("\\((.+?)\\)",y)
             regmatches(y,m)[[1]][2]
           })
           vals <-  as.list( x )
           names(vals) <- unlist(vars)
           data.frame( vals, 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
         })  %>% rbind_all
```

which gives me your desired result (with good-looking variable names too)

Comment: Variables are 9, your solutions ends up with a data frame with 24 variables.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Fixed that -- it seems there are 11 variables though (some were not listed in the example: "subclass" and "suborder")

Comment: You are right. The list of columns I want is 9 long. I want to drop subclass and suborder as those are not consistent and don't really mean anything for my purposes. Great answer!

Comment: Using `strsplit(Test$Taxa,"\\(.+?\\)(_|$)")` will avoid the need for all the `regmatches` extraction stuff.

Comment: @thelatemail that would likely end up being a very different solution.  OP needs to know characters inside parentheses: superkingdom, phylum,  etc. in order to put the right value in the right column. Just strsplitting would not be enough.

Comment: @akhmed - If it always goes down from kingdom --> strain it shouldn't matter if it pulls up early. It would only matter really if a particular level was jumped, which I can't see how it would in a biological hierarchy.

Comment: @thelatemail, it actually does jump levels. See for yourself: sometimes 5th split (right after "class") is "order" and sometimes it is "subclass" and then it is followed by other required columns. To be honest I don't see how one can solve it without looking what's inside parentheses.

Comment: @akhmed - fair point. Well spotted. Maybe something using named regexpr capture groups? Probably getting outside of my area of expertise now though.